# Overlapping components of same width and height

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to implement ReactNative layout containing two components, where 2nd component overlaps 1st one and has the same width, possibly also same height (without hardcoding width/height of course)? It is easy to implement something like that in native Android, but I can't find example for ReactNative. I'd be surprised if it is not possible though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try below

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }} >
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    // 1st component
  <View>
  <View style={StyleSheet.absolueFill}>
    // 2st component
  <View>
<View>
```